# powershell + PS2EXE-v0.5.0.0 + windows forms

Tags: windows, forms, powershell

I need to compile ps1 to exe. It works fine, but when i've added some windows.forms elements (open file dialog and select dir) it is still compiling but forms are not showing. Then I noticed, that forms are not showing even when I start script with RMB -> Exec with Powershell. But everything works fine in ISE.
Does anybody have similar problem?

```
Function Get-OpenFile($initialDirectory)
{ 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |
Out-Null

$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
$OpenFileDialog.filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt"
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$OpenFileDialog.filename
$OpenFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true
}

function Select-Folder($message='Folder to save', $path = 0) { 
$object = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application  

$folder = $object.BrowseForFolder(0, $message, 0, $path) 
if ($folder -ne $null) { 
    $folder.self.Path 

   } 
}
```

The rest of the code is just parser and renamer. 
UPD - Problem is exactly with windows.forms, when I've comment #get-openfile(myDir) , select-folder dialog has been shown. And shows up, after compiling to exe.

Comment: perhaps share a little few code for more understand and helping you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, nevermind, i just refused open-file dialog.